# Using a cronjob to clean /tmp

Tags: cron, tmp

Is it safe to use a bash script and a cronjob to empty `/tmp` automatically, or should I do this differently?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`/tmp` is cleaned on every system reboot, but for systems that cannot be rebooted often, and specially if the only objective is to clean `/tmp` a script can be made to clean it.

No process should keep important data there but it is important that you are able to clean `/tmp` without disrupting any processes writing data in `tmp`.

I recommend to use `tmpreaper` for that.

You can install it with `sudo apt-get install tmpreaper`.

From the man page:

> tmpreaper recursively searches for and removes files and empty directories which haven't been accessed for a given number of seconds.  Normally, it's used to clean up  directories which are used for temporary holding space, such as "/tmp".  Please read the WARNINGS section of this manual.

Usage normally involves invoking `tmpreaper` in `/tmp` with a time spec argument. The time spec argument can be anything from `d` for days, `h` for hours, `m` for minutes, or `s` for seconds.

Please use the `--test` to dry run and get an output of the results before you actually run the command. That will get you an idea of what will be deleted before you actually commit any changes to the file system.

Comment: Thank you! To fully answer my question, can you explain me why this is better than using a simple recursive remove?

Comment: Its not, its just simpler to use and the arguments used are more understandable. A simple `rm -rf` on a list of files returned by `find` would do the job also. This is "just another way", not even saying is the best one, just the one I use on the servers I setup.

Comment: `tmpreaper` seems like a good tool, worth using `--test` and `--showdeletes` when testing.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding a cronjob which executes

```
find /tmp/* -type d -mtime +5 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf 
find /tmp/* -type f -mtime +5 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

This would delete all files older than 5 days.

Comment: There's no point passing -r to the rm command in the second example, which is only finding files anyway, right?